# Get unique value from lines else take default value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of sales lines each having a currency field.
A sale line is represented by the table SALE_LINE which has a field, Currency, to store the currency of the sales line.

I want to do an SQL request which will take a list of sales line and if the currency of these sales lines is unique to them all,
then take that currency or else set the value to a default one like the dollar.

As in if I have 3 lines with currencies: EUR, GBP, ZAR, the request would return me the DOL.
if I have 3 lines with currencies: EUR, EUR, EUR, the request would return me the EUR.

My SQL request is as below:

```
DECLARE
    @salesLineIds VARCHAR(MAX),
    @defaultCurrency VARCHAR(10),
    @uniqueCurrency VARCHAR(10)

SET @salesLineIds = '1,2,3';
SET defaultCurrency = 'DOL';

DECLARE
    @ID_LIST table (Id BIGINT)
    
INSERT INTO @ID_LIST SELECT TRY_CAST(value AS BIGINT)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@salesLineIds, ',')

SELECT @uniqueCurrency =(CASE WHEN 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SL.Currency))
THEN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT SL_CUR.Currency
    from SALE_LINE SL_CUR
    where SL_CUR.Id in (SELECT * FROM @ID_LIST)
    )
ELSE 
    @defaultCurrency
END)
FROM SALE_LINE SL
WHERE SL.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @ID_LIST)
```

The above works but it might not be good performance.  Is there any way where I can improve the performance of the above query?

The below query does not give the good currency:

```
SELECT @uniqueCurrency =(CASE WHEN 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SL.Currency))
THEN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT SL.Currency
    )
ELSE 
    @defaultCurrency
END)
FROM SALE_LINE SL
WHERE SL.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @ID_LIST)
group by SL.Currency
```

Any help of how I can do better in the working SQL will be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: "but it might not be good performance" - is it a measured performance problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat : I also want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: better? in what way?

Comment: USD is a currency. AUD is a currency, CAD is a currency. But DOL is not a currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group over the *whole set*, then simply check for distinct `Currency` values. If there is only one then you can just use any aggregation, such as `MIN`, to get it.

```sql
DECLARE
    @salesLineIds VARCHAR(MAX),
    @defaultCurrency VARCHAR(10),
    @uniqueCurrency VARCHAR(10);

SET @salesLineIds = '1,2,3';
SET defaultCurrency = 'DOL';

DECLARE
    @ID_LIST table (Id BIGINT);
    
INSERT INTO @ID_LIST SELECT TRY_CAST(value AS BIGINT)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@salesLineIds, ',');

SELECT @uniqueCurrency =
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT SL.Currency) = 1
    THEN MIN(SL.Currency)
    ELSE @defaultCurrency
  END
FROM SALE_LINE SL
WHERE SL.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @ID_LIST);
```

> I suggest `CHAR(3)` as a suitable data type for currency

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no nulls.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN min(SL.Currency) = max(SL.Currency)
        THEN min(SL.Currency)
        ELSE @defaultCurrency
    END
FROM SALE_LINE SL
WHERE SL.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @ID_LIST);
```

Comment: I am not sure the above will work with 3 lines with currencies: EUR, GBP, EUR

Comment: It's essentially the same as the other answer. In your example min does not equal max which falls through as required.